# Redirect button via Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have a contact form inserted into my website via an iframe.  I am unable to modify the contact form but I can insert some javascript within the iframe itself.  I would like to have the contact form redirect the user to a new page upon successfully submitting the form.  That new page should load in the parent page and not the iframe.  Any ideas how I could accomplish this?  This is the page i'm trying to modify http://www.oneupland.com/contact

Comment: I'm not sure if u can get submit action from iframe w/o access.. So i think there is no way how to do that and probably u get permission denied..

Comment: I do have access to the iframe but it is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

After a successful submission try executing either of the below

`window.location.href="https://stackoverflow.com"`
or
`window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");`

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if u can access it but u can try something like this..

```
// keep a reference to the window element of the iframe :
   var winIFrame = window.frames["myFrame"].contentWindow;

// with this you can access any DOM element in the iframe
   winIFrame.document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() { 
     window.location.replace("http://your_redirect.com");
     return false;
   }
```